# Angular useHash vs. providing HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular, angular-routing

From the official documentation the difference between using `{useHash: true}` when importing the `RouterModule` and providing `HashLocationStrategy` as a `LocationStrategy` in the `AppModule` is unclear to me.

I would assume that `useHash` is just a shortcut to tell Angular to use the `HashLocationStrategy`, thus both variants being equivalent, but I didn't find any clear documentation saying so.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question recently, so I dug into the source code a bit and it does indeed look like its the case that it's just a shortcut when using `RouterModule.forRoot`.  The `forRoot` method takes a config object and returns a configured module with providers.

```js
...
config?.useHash ? provideHashLocationStrategy() : providePathLocationStrategy(),
...
```

and that internal method just provides the hash location strategy.

```js
// Note: For internal use only with `RouterModule`. Standalone setup via `provideRouter` should
// provide hash location directly via `{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}`.
function provideHashLocationStrategy(): Provider {
  return {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy};
}
```

Here's the relevant location in the code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/79001a7e30dcb6b86eac96eecedd589d6515ec37/packages/router/src/router_module.ts#L152